# How to query deep jsonb in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb column (called `info`) in Postgres which structure looks like this:

```
{ name: 'john', house_id: null, extra_attrs: [{ attr_id: 4, attr_value: 'a value' }, { attr_id: 5, attr_value: 'another value' }] }
```

It can have N `extra_attrs` but we know that each of them will have just two keys: the `attr_id` and the `attr_value`.

Now, what is the best way to query for `info` that has `extra_attrs` with a specific `attr_id` and `attr_value`. I have done it like this, and it works:

Given the following data structure to query for:

```
[{ attr_id: 4, values: ['a value', 'something else'] }, { attr_id: 5, values: ['another value'] }]
```

The following query works:

```
select * from people
where (info @> '{"extra_attrs": [{ "attr_id": 4, "attr_value": "a value" }]} OR info @> '{"extra_attrs": [{ "attr_id": 4, "attr_value": "something else" }]) AND info @> '{"extra_attrs": [{ "attr_id": 5, "attr_value": "another value" }]}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do so or this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternate method would involve [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and transforming data to apply the filter on:

```
SELECT people.info
FROM people,
LATERAL (SELECT DISTINCT True is_valid
         FROM jsonb_array_elements(info->'extra_attrs') y
         WHERE (y->>'attr_id', y->>'attr_value') IN (
             ('4', 'a value'), 
             ('4', 'something else'),
             ('5','another value')
         )
) y
WHERE is_valid
```

I believe this method more convenient for dynamic filters since the id/value pairs are added in only 1 place.

A similar (and perhaps slightly faster) method would use `WHERE EXISTS` and compare json documents like below.

```
SELECT people.info
FROM people
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRUE 
       FROM jsonb_array_elements(info->'extra_attrs') attrs
       WHERE attrs @> ANY(ARRAY[
           JSONB '{ "attr_id": 4, "attr_value": "a value" }',
           JSONB '{ "attr_id": 4, "attr_value": "something else" }',
           JSONB '{ "attr_id": 5, "attr_value": "another value" }'
              ]
       )
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure which method would be faster. it would probably depend on the data. if you have a test dataset, please run the three queries (yours, and the two I suggest) and post the execution times here.